# Terminology for UI Features / Components

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am in the process of learning and building my first website using HTML/CSS.

I have come across several nifty tricks that rely solely on CSS or sometimes on CSS+HTML to create a variety of UI features (or should I call them widgets or components?). I want to learn more about these, but I can't find proper name(s) for such features.

From what little I have been able to learn, some of them are commonly known as: Accordions, Tabs, Carousel (slider), Flip-boxes, etc.

Is there any authentic/reliable source where I can learn proper names of these CSS features or widgets, and then learn more about using them in my work.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't mind the down votes...if the question does not have the merit, so be it. But for someone who is learning and using vanilla CSS, it is quite frustrating to search and learn "how to achieve this type of effect" without knowing what it is actually called. It is like talking on phone with sign language.

Answer (score 0):

These are the most common HTML/CSS/Javascript frameworks to build websites.
Go through with their Documentation.

[ZurbFoundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/)

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: For now I don't plan to use any CSS framework, but perhaps learning these frameworks would also teach me the names of these commonly used CSS features. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. That's great. You can learn and get idea about what are the most important components use for create websites.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to some CSS frameworks like Bootstrap, Semantic-ui. They will have a bunch of css components/elements under them.

Use [Semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html) page to get started

Comment: Plus 1 for the semantic-ui link. Can't up-vote yet...not enough credibility it seems :(